# Curl says it cannot resolve host but host can be resolved

Tags: http, curl, terminal

I replaced mywebsite with the correct website that can be resolved when I run curl www.mywebsite.com. These are the options I am using:

```
curl -X 'GET https://www.mywebsite.com/Web2/PDF.aspx?page=1' \
-H 'Host: www.mywebsite.org' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36 OPR/51.0.2830.26' \  
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'DNT: 1' \
-e 'the-referer' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
-b '_the-cookies'
```

When I try to run this in OSX terminal, the following happens:

```
$ curl -X 'GET https://www.mywebsite.com/Web2/PDF.aspx?page=1' \
-H 'Host: www.mywebsite.org' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36 OPR/51.0.2830.26' \  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  
Mac-mini-3:~ myuser$
```

It says:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host:

Why is this happening? And why is it trying to run commands when I used the \ escape sequence in terminal? It should not be running any commands until all the options are passed.

Comment: Side Note: By default you use curl without explicitly saying which request method to use. If you just pass in a HTTP URL like curl http://example.com it will use GET. If you use -d or -F curl will use POST, -I will cause a HEAD and -T will make it a PUT. If for whatever reason you're not happy with these default choices that curl does for you, you can override those request methods by specifying -X [WHATEVER]. This way you can for example send a DELETE by doing curl -X DELETE [URL].

Comment: the Accept header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what content types they'll accept. The server will then send back a response, which will include a Content-Type header telling the client what the content type of the returned content actually is. However, as you may have noticed, HTTP requests can also contain Content-Type headers. Why? Well, think about POST or PUT requests. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers

Comment: The HTTP referer is an HTTP header field that identifies the address of the webpage (i.e. the URI or IRI) that linked to the resource being requested. n the most common situation this means that when a user clicks a hyperlink in a web browser, the browser sends a request to the server holding the destination webpage. The request includes the referer field, which indicates the last page the user was on (the one where they clicked the link).

Comment: An HTTP cookie is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored on the user's computer by the user's web browser while the user is browsing. Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites to remember stateful information (such as items added in the shopping cart in an online store). The server sends the following in its response header to set a cookie field: Set-Cookie:name=value. If there is a cookie set, then the browser sends the following in its request header: Cookie:name=value.

Comment: Why do all browsers' user agents start with “Mozilla/”? Because of User agent spoofing. The popularity of various Web browser products has varied throughout the Web's history, and this has influenced the design of websites in such a way that websites are sometimes designed to work well only with particular browsers, rather than according to uniform standards. Websites often include code to detect browser version to adjust the page design sent according to the user agent string received. Thus, various browsers have a feature to spoof their identification to force certain server-side content.

Comment: Keep-alive connections allow the client and server to use the same TCP connection to send and receive multiple HTTP requests and responses. This helps avoid 3-way handshake for new connections— a full roundtrip of latency slow-start Keep-alive connections are enabled by default in HTTP/1.1 while not in HTTP/1.0. HTTP/1.0 was designed to close the connection after every request between client and server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have not specified a host. The host is specified as a request command (part of -X arg).

You need to have (note the placement of single quote)

curl -X GET 'https://www.mywebsite.com/Web2/PDF.aspx?page=1' ...

Comment: There was one other important point I want to mention. I had a space after one of the \ escape sequences. And that was breaking the entire command as well.